# Create multiple retrofit instances for two different base URL`s using dagger2 and MVVM

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I am trying to implement multiple instance of retrofit for two different base URL`s using Dagger2 and MVVM. I have already wasted a huge amount of time testing different approaches provided here in SO, but still unable to figure it out. I have created  new Qualifiers as well and created a new instance but all my request are still made using first instance.Here is my implementation.

**Qualifiers**

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class APIService1

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class APIService2
```

**AppModule class**

```
@AssistedModule
@Suppress("unused")
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class, CoreDataModule::class, AssistedViewModelModule::class, AssistedInject_AppModule::class])
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideServices(
        APIService1 okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ) =
        provideService(okHttpClient, converterFactory, MyApi::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @APIService2
    fun provideMicroServices(
        APIService1 okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ) =
        provideMicroService(okHttpClient, converterFactory, MyApi::class.java)

    @APIService1
    @Provides
    fun providePrivateOkHttpClient(upstreamClient: OkHttpClient): OkHttpClient {
        return upstreamClient.newBuilder().build()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides    
    fun provideRemoteDataSource(myApiService: MyApi) = RemoteDataSource(myApiService)
    
 private fun createRetrofit(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ): Retrofit {        
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example1.com/api/")
                .client(okhttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .build()
        
    }

    private fun createMicroServiceRetrofit(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ): Retrofit {        
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example2.com/api/")
                .client(okhttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .build()
        
    }

    private fun <T> provideService(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory, clazz: Class<T>
    ): T {
        return createRetrofit(okhttpClient, converterFactory).create(clazz)
    }

    private fun <T> provideMicroService(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory, clazz: Class<T>
    ): T {
        return createMicroServiceRetrofit(okhttpClient, converterFactory).create(clazz)
    }
}
```

**CoreDataModule class**

```
@Module
class CoreDataModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)

        return client.build()
    }
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshiConverterFactory(): MoshiConverterFactory =
        MoshiConverterFactory.create()
}
```

**RemoteDataSource Class**

```
@Keep
class RemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(private val service: MyApi) : BaseDataSource() {

    suspend fun getOtp(data: String) = getResult { service.getOtp(data) }

    suspend fun getData(data: String) = getResult { service.getData(data) }
    
}
```

**BaseDataSource Class**

```
abstract class BaseDataSource {

    protected suspend fun <T> getResult(call: suspend () -> Response<T>): Result<T> {
            val response = call()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val body = response.body()                
                if (body != null) return Result.success(body)
            }
            return error(" ${response.code()} ${response.message()}")
    }
}
```

**MyApi Class**

```
interface MyApi {

    @POST("Register/Otp")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun getOtp(@Field("data") data: String): Response<OtpResponse>

    @POST("Home/Data")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun getData(@Field("data") data: String): Response<DataResponse>
    
}
```

This is how i am using it in my ViewModel

**One of My ViewModles**

```
class OtpViewModel @Inject constructor(
     private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource
) :
    ViewModel() {

    fun getNewOtp() = liveData {
        try {
            emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
            val response = remoteDataSource.getOtp(params))
            emit(Resource.success(data = response))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(Resource.error(data = null, message = e.message ?: e.localizedMessage.orEmpty()))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 annotations like this:

```kotlin
@Qualifier
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER, AnnotationTarget.FIELD, 
    AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ApiService1

@Qualifier
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER, AnnotationTarget.FIELD, 
    AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ApiService2
```

Change your providers with:

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton
@ApiService1
fun provideServices(....): MyApi {
  return ...
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@ApiService2
fun provideMicroServices(....): MyApi {
  return ...
}
```

Then in your Android classes you can do this:

```kotlin
class MyActivity : FragmentActivity() {
  @Inject
  @ApiService1
  lateinit var retrofit1: MyApi

  @Inject
  @ApiService2
  lateinit var retrofit2: MyApi

  ....
}
```

Or in classes:

```kotlin
class Repository @Inject constructor (
  @ApiService1 retrofit1: MyApi
) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear :)